# 554 5.7.1 <mail_addr>: Relay access denied centos postfix

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I have problem in send mail from postfix in centos

I have following [setup mail server postfix](http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/02/08/setup-mail-server-using-postfixdovecotsquirrelmail-in-centosrhelscientific-linux-6-3-step-by-step/) for sending mail but I am getting error.

As in the link I tried following commands

**telnet localhost smtp**

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
250-mydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:<domain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<test@gmail.com>
554 5.7.1 <test@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

**Edit-1**

In terminal this works

```
echo TEST | mail -v -s "Test mail" testing@gmail.com
```

my `postconf -n` shows belog information

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = dummy.com
myhostname = dummy.com
mynetworks = all
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

What configuration I have to perform to send mails from my server.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks), setting mynetworks = all doesn't appear to be valid, and if you specifically set mynetworks to something, then mynetworks_style is ignored.

Reset mynetworks back to its default value if you want to use mynetworks_style=host, or explicitly set mynetworks to reflect where mail is being sent from (usually localhost and your local subnet).  For example:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24
mynetworks_style = subnet
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying you relay email to gmail but  your configuration does not accept relaying mails to gmail so  it returns 554 reject code. 
  in [postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html%23relay_domains_reject_code)

> relay_domains_reject_code (default: 554) The numerical Postfix SMTP
>   server response code when a client request is rejected by the
>   reject_unauth_destination recipient restriction.

to fix relaying  problem correct value of  **mydestination** parameter according to [postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html%23relay_domains)

> relay_domains (default: $mydestination) What destination domains (and
>   subdomains thereof) this system will relay mail to. For details about
>   how the relay_domains value is used, see the description of the
>   permit_auth_destination and reject_unauth_destination SMTP recipient
>   restrictions.
>
> Domains that match $relay_domains are delivered with the
>   $relay_transport mail delivery transport. The SMTP server validates
>   recipient addresses with $relay_recipient_maps and rejects
>   non-existent recipients. See also the relay domains address class in
>   the ADDRESS_CLASS_README file.
>
> Note: Postfix will not automatically forward mail for domains that
>   list this system as their primary or backup MX host. See the
>   permit_mx_backup restriction in the postconf(5) manual page.
>
> Specify a list of host or domain names, "/file/name" patterns or
>   "type:table" lookup tables, separated by commas and/or whitespace.
>   Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace. A
>   "/file/name" pattern is replaced by its contents; a "type:table"
>   lookup table is matched when a (parent) domain appears as lookup key.
>   Specify "!pattern" to exclude a domain from the list. The form
>   "!/file/name" is supported only in Postfix version 2.4 and later.
>
> Pattern matching of domain names is controlled by the presence or
>   absence of "relay_domains" in the parent_domain_matches_subdomains
>   parameter value.